# Javascript click on a button returns 'undefined' although the item is found

Tags: javascript

I am trying to automate some clicks. I will send javascript to the browser via AppleScript.
One example is in google sheets.
I would like to click on the highlight color button with the following code running in the **browser console**.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('goog-color-menu-button-indicator')[0].click()
```

But it returns undefined error. But actually the button is found by the first part of the  expression.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('goog-color-menu-button-indicator')[0]

<div class="goog-color-menu-button-indicator" style="border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); user-select: none;">
    <div class="docs-icon goog-inline-block " style="user-select: none;">
        <div class="docs-icon-img-container docs-icon-img docs-icon-text-color" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;">&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another example is Tableau Server download button.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('download')[0]
```

returns

```
<div class="tabToolbarButton tab-widget download" role="button" data-tb-test-id="download-ToolbarButton" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Download" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
<span class="tabToolbarButtonImg tab-icon-download"></span>
<span class="tabToolbarButtonText">Download</span>
</div>
```

But how do I click on it?

Comment: You are accessing the element before it exists. `getElementsByClassName` is a live collection so it adds it when it is rendered on the page.

Comment: if it doesn't exist, how does it find it before the click? what should I do?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: this is how it looks like https://imgur.com/a/V1xK7EW

Comment: click does not return anything.... so of course it would be undefined. If the click event is not being registered, then they bound the click event to something else. Or the do something else with the event. Hard to guess without knowing how they are detecting a click.

Comment: I am facing similar issue @se02ijtx any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the body did not load, make sure to add an event listener "load".
you better not throw your javascript code directly in html

Comment: Thanks. I edited the first part of the question to make my use case more clear.
I will send javascript to the browser via AppleScript. One example is in google sheets. I would like to click on the highlight color button with the following code running in the browser console.